# Rails has_many association issue in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, has-many

I have a company model designed with the devise , and when the company is logged in the company can create the event so that the company has many events and events belong to company the events controller is given as

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :company_signed_in?
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def new
    @event = current_company.events.build
  end

  def create
    @event = current_company.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:success] = "Profile saved"
      redirect_to company_events_path(current_company)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = current_company.events.where(id: params[:id]).first
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :company_id, :category_id, :event_date, :event_info, :place, :event_avatar)
  end

end
```

and the company model has

```
has_many :events
```

and the event model has

```
belongs_to :company
```

the new view of the event has

```
   <%= form_for [current_company, @event] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
```

and the show view has

```
<%= @event.name %>
```

my routes are

```
resources :companies do
    resource :company_profile, :events
  end
```

now what i want to do is the current company can create an event and when the event is created it should be redirected to the show page of the event just produced

i need to create an event so that i can get the url like `companies/3/events/3` this type of url

issue is when i am going to the show action i am getting undefined method 'name' Please help ! and in the log i have

```
Started GET "/companies/3/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-30 16:41:54 +0530
Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"company_id"=>"3"}
  Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 3  ORDER BY `companies`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CompanyProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `company_profiles`.* FROM `company_profiles` WHERE `company_profiles`.`company_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`company_id` = 3 AND `events`.`id` IS NULL  ORDER BY `events`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: 
    2: <label>Name : </label>
    3: <%= @event.name %>
    4: <%= @event.event_date %></br></br>
    5: <label>Age : </label>
    6: <%= @event.place %></br></br>
  app/views/events/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_events_show_html_erb__541678279__634038278'
```

Comment: Can you clarify please, _issue is i am not able to create a new event_? Any errors? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: it is rendering the new action again

Comment: when it is render the new action?

Comment: There should be some error. Can you post your logs please?

Comment: when i hit the submit button

this is in the console
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JJPwiClneDLnXUiHqn4BO8OtkelWqwqMwPyc4cCAhu7Tb5RvkmHXIC6LWG16wBm02uLodZtQ4TYxB/WE6smozg==", "event"=>{"name"=>"wwee", "commit"=>"Create Event", "company_id"=>"3"}
  Company Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = 3  ORDER BY `companies`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  CompanyProfile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `company_profiles`.* FROM `company_profiles` WHERE `company_profiles`.`company_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

Comment: You should check the validation in your model, you have `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: okay i had validation issue but still i am getting error 

undefined method `name'
and now it is storing in the database but i am not able to get in the show action

Comment: it's is a debugging question, i downvote.

Comment: i have changed the issue of the question

Comment: Please Post your errors as it is.

Comment: SO it isn't a debugging tool, show your efforts. I don't wanna make your job.

Comment: @Pavan i have given the logs in the question

Comment: Your `@event` is nil. Has the event created in the ***DB***?

Comment: yes the record is created

Answer (score 0):

You should try the below method and see if it works:

```
def show
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing id of event to the show action. only company_id is passed as shown in parameters

```
   Parameters: {"company_id"=>"3"}
```

so when it queries in the event with id `NULL` it didnt find any event and hence `null.name` is crashing

Either pass `id` of event to the show action. or for testing you should do this

```
def show
  @event = current_company.events.first
end
```